# How to set the text size for the textviews inside a viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-preferences

I have a `ViewPager` where I inflate a layout containing `TextViews` and the text inside of these text views changes from one page to another what I need is to change the TextSize of these `TextViews` but for example if I have several page in the `ViewPager`.

I need all the `TextViews` in all the pages to have same text size and that this size don't change unless I resized it again!!

Comment: Try to use `Preferences` where you can save your size of text and fetch it and set it wherever you want inside your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to save your `FontSize` value under `Preferences`. Following snippet shows how to add `KEY` and `VALUE` under `Preferences`.

```
SharedPreferences  pref=getSharedPreferences(MyPref,MODE_PRIVATE);              
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=pref.edit();            
editor.putFloat(FONT_SIZE_KEY,ed1.getTextSize());
editor.commit();
```

Once the `KEY` & `VALUE` pair saved under `Preferences`. Fetch the value through the `KEY` you used at save time. Below snippet shows how to fetch `VALUE` from `KEY` saved under specific preference `MyPref`.

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences(MyPref, MODE_PRIVATE);
final float fontsize=prefs.getFloat(FONT_SIZE_KEY, 12);
EditTextName.setTextSize(fontsize); //  here EditTextName is the EDITTEXT name on which setTextSize() used to set the text size which is fetched over  preference.
```

Comment: thanks I've already done that but the first two pages in the viewpager are not changing the fontsize but the next two pages are then when I swipe through the Viewpaager all the pages font size is modified but how to let my current page directly changes its size I used adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); But that didn't work.